# Scaling dsfont without scalerel (any alternatives?)

Tags: fonts, scaling, scale, scalerel

My problem is as follows: I would like to use the upright `fourier` package symbols together with `dsfont`. This produces:

[image]

I therefore want to scale the `dsfont` symbols down to the same size as the `fourier` letters (or vice versa scale fourier up).

I tried using `scalerel`, however for some reason pdflatex and Anki (a flashcard software) doesn't seem to like this. It declares no error message, however it doesn't scale the symbol (or any others I've tried for that matter). Overleaf does scale with the same code, so it's not the code. Are there any alternatives to `scalerel` to scale `dsfont` (or scale the `fourier` package - although this isn't preferred). I've also tried using the `mathalfa` package to load `dsfont` (although this doesn't load), as it has a scale feature.

Some notes: I'm using `mathastext` with `nosmalldelims` enabled, if this makes a difference.

Any help is appreciated:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I measured the heights of `\mathds{R}` and `R`, finding 6.83331pt for the former and 6.51pt for the latter.

Since 6.51/6.83331 is approximately 0.9527, the solution is “easy”: load yourself the definition for `\mathds` and the `dsrom` font, with a scaling factor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{dsrom}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{dsrom}{m}{n}{
  <-10>   s*[0.9527] dsrom8
  <10-12> s*[0.9527] dsrom10
  <12->   s*[0.9527] dsrom12
}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathds}{U}{dsrom}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$\mathds{R}$R

\end{document}
```

[image]

The actual height of `\mathds{R}` turns out to be 6.51009pt, but the difference is unnoticeable with the naked eye.

I also made experiments at various font sizes and the correspondence is correct in every case.

Of course `dsfont` symbols don't blend with `fourier`, but that's a different matter.

Comment: I haven't found a better alternative to dsfont, which has a bb version of the number 1 (for indicators). Do you have any suggestions, which could be implemented in the same or a preferred way to this? Also, thank you for the solution:)

Comment: Also, I can see, that you've fixed some mistakes in my post. Thank you, English is not my first language:)

Comment: Strangely, the top of blackboard letter is distinctly above the top of R (as one can confirm on screen tracing horizontal lines for example while taking a screenshot capture).  I guess the problem is not due to the visible depth having contributed to your height evaluation, but maybe in connection with how the boundary box of the glyph was designed.  Anyway it looks as if reducing a bit the scale factor could help here.

Comment: @user691586 The fourier R doesn't really reach its height.